# How do I code sign an Electron app before bundling it (for Mac)?

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I am developing an Electron application for Mac OS X. I am attempting to test its auto-update feature while developing locally, *prior to bundling it as a `.app`*.

I have a built one initial version of my application, `Foo.app`, along with a `.dmg` and `.zip`, using the `electron-builder` module, to use as the update. I have hosted these files. I have verified that they install and run correctly. And I have a Squirrel server, running locally, that will return a correct JSON payload pointing to that `.zip`.

For developing my application locally, I am using Webpack to transpile my web assets, and using `electron@1.4.4` to launch those assets in Electron. In other words, when developing locally, I am not launching the bundled `.app`; I am launching a dev server and serving those assets in Electron. The process is similar to running `$ electron .`.

The problem occurs when the auto-update hook is called, at this line:

```
autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feedURL)
```

This line raises an Electron error that says:

```
"Could not get code signature for running application."
```

OK, so I do a search and see that there are a handful of guides that explain how to code sign an application:

- http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2015/08/14/codesigning-electron-applications/
- https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-osx-sign/wiki/1.-Getting-Started
- https://discuss.atom.io/t/electron-app-signing-procedure/19124

But, these indicate that I should code sign the `.app`. As I have stated, I am trying to test auto-update *before* I bundle it as a `.app`. I would prefer not to rebuild again and again until I get auto-update working correctly.

So I do another search and see there are several forum questions that are more-or-less the same as what I am asking:

- https://discuss.atom.io/t/problem-with-auto-updater/14537
- https://discuss.atom.io/t/could-not-get-code-signature-for-running-application/30405
- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7476

I'm having trouble grokking the solution from digging through these threads. I'm hoping someone can give me a clear solution to signing an Electron app before bundling it.

---

**For an answer, I am hoping to get a clear answer on all of these:**

- Is it possible to code sign my Electron app prior to bundling it as a `.app`? I.e., the files that I would launch with `$ electron .`?
- If yes, how?
- If not, why? And is there any way to speed up testing this?

Comment: My current belief is that *it is not possible* to code sign prior to bundling the app. If you want to test a feature such as auto-update, you will simply have to bundle the app, code sign that, and then test the feature within the bundled app. I don't know this for a fact; I'm just putting it out there in case others see this question and want some kind of workable (albeit frustrating) alternative.

Comment: I have just ran into the same issue. Frustrating...

Answer (score 3):

Long shot and I have not verified this.

Squirrel.Mac checks the signing of the currently running application[[1](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Mac/blob/203315f93e41086a2ab9d1ab2f5f8663878f145a/Squirrel/SQRLUpdater.m#L164)], this is the `AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName` executable when you are running a packaged app. Which basically is a renamed electron executable.

But when you run `electron .` it will run the executable from your `node/bin` directory. Electron is not signed by default, so if you sign it the auto updater might succeed with the cert check.

**So basically:**

1. Find electron: `which electron`
2. Change working directory to the electron path
3. Sign electron with `codesign -s "Developer ID Application: YourCompanyName" electron`
4. Validate the code signature with `codesign -dvvv electron`

Hopefully that should cut it.